# Take mean while ignoring specific set of values in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data:

```
values = data.frame(score = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 999, 2, 3, 999, 4),
                    score_2 = c(1, 4, 8 , 4, 999, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0))
values %>% 
  summarize(mean_score = mean(score),
            mean_score_2 = mean(score_2))
```

I want to compute the mean of each of the columns in the dataset while ignoring the value "999."

So I can do something like this:

```
values %>% 
  filter_all(all_vars(!grepl('999',.))) %>%
  summarize(mean_score = mean(score),
            mean_score_2 = mean(score_2))
```

But this will remove rows 6, 9, and 5 from both score and score_2 (because that's the location of 999).  How do I selectively compute the means while ignoring certain values without eliminating entire rows?

For `score` the resulting output should be `3`, for `score_2` the resulting output should be `2.78`

Comment: Try `values %>% summarise_all(~ mean(.[.!= 999]))`

Comment: You may consider `na.strings` in `read.table` to handle the 999 upstream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `summarise_all` or `summarise_if` (only to select `numeric` columns) and select the column values by a comparison operator (`!=`).

```
library(dplyr)
values %>%
     summarise_all(~ mean(.[.!= 999]))
```

If there are multiple values, use `%in%` and negate `!`

```
values %>%
     summarise_all(~ mean(.[! . %in% c(999, 994)]))
```

Comment: or `values %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("score")), ~mean(ifelse( . == 999, NA, .), na.rm = T))`

Answer (score 2):

You may consider this as as well:

```
values %>% 
    gather(key = "score_type", value = "val") %>% 
    filter(val != 999) %>% 
    group_by(score_type) %>% 
    summarise(mean_score = mean(val)) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

## Results

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  score_type mean_score
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 score            3   
2 score_2          2.78
```

---

## Notes

IMHO the solution gives you the following benefits:

- Brings you closer to [Tidy Data[PDF]](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf)idea of handling data in `dplyr`. I if you intend to derive summary statistics by score type this appears to be a preferred data format.
- You can easily expand the filter in a readable manner. If you want to use **`~`** notation you will end up doing something like that for addittional operations:

  ```
  values %>%
      summarise_all(list( ~ mean(.[!. %in% c(999, 994)]), 
                          ~ max(.[!. %in% c(999, 994)])))
  ```

  This is impractical as for a more complex filter you will end up with unreadable statements or a vector that you will have to create and bring for that reason only. Also, results are not nicely formatted

  ```
  #   score_mean score_2_mean score_max score_2_max
  # 1          3     2.777778         5           8
  ```